# Windows 10 stuck on Blue Restarting screen

Tags: windows-10, asus-laptop

During the night, my Asus laptop apparently updated Windows 10, and now my computer is stuck on the blue Restarting screen (with the circle spinning). I cannot Ctrl+Alt+DLT, cannot F8 into BIOS or safe mode, or anything. I've unplugged all peripherals, I've turned it off and back on multiple times, with no change. I even went as far as to download a Microsoft Windows 10 recovery program onto a USB and plugged it in - but the laptop won't acknowledge it! My laptop is 4 years old but still runs in very good condition. I don't know what to do to fix this. I had the computer on for at least an hour while getting the recovery USB, and it stayed "Restarting." Help!

Comment: What exactly did you download?  Do you know you can enter force Windows into the Advance Startup Mode so you can attempt a Safe Mode boot in Windows 8 and above my causing Windows to fail to load 3 times in a row.

Comment: Entry into Bios or Safe Mode is not going to work, once windows has started loading.  You have to be faster with your keypresses.  First turn the power off, wait 10 secs, turn it on and then hit your keys.

Comment: try to boot from external drive (CD/DVD/USB Flash) if You can. You may need to enter BIOS and select bootable device. Check PC manufacturer documentation how to recover OS.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix?